# PHP Генерация промокодов и проверка в бд

Tags: php, база-данных, while, generate

```
function checkPromo($promo) {
  global $db;
  $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `coupons` WHERE `coupon` = $promo");
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
$promo = newPromo(); // Возвращает набор случайных символов
$checkPromo = checkPromo($promo);

while(!chekPromo) {
  $promo = newPromo(); // Возвращает набор случайных символов
  $checkPromo = checkPromo($promo);
}
if ($checkPromo) {
  $db->query("..."); //Добавляю новую запись в бд
}
```

Такой код подойдет для проверки промокода в бд?

Comment: Запрос кривой, условие в checkPromo() лишнее, последнее условие тоже лишнее, вместо while лучше использовать do while.

Comment: ` do while` ? Теперь представьте, что генерируют промокод из 4 символов из латинницы, и в какой то момент этот код уйдет в вечность. Нельзя делать такие запросы в цикле, вам ли об этом не знать